# Label Printing From C# - Document Size Is Too Large For Printer

Tags: c#, printing

I'm developing an application which must print labels. The label printer i'm using is a Brother QL-570. The label width is 66mm and the length of the labels needs to be approximately 45mm. The problem I'm having is that I am unable to configure the application to actually print the labels. Everytime I do so I receive a warning stating that the document size is too large for the printer. No matter what size I attempt to change the PrintDocument size to I always receieve a warning stating that the document is 90mm x 29mm and is too large for the label printer.

Here's just one of my attempts:

```
private PrintDocument label;


label = new PrintDocument();
PaperSize pS = new PaperSize("Custom Size", 212, 67);
label.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pS;
label.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Brother QL-570";
label.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pS;
label.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(label_PrintPage);

private void label_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Font header = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold);

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", header, brush, 30, 30);

}
```

Has anyone any idea where I'm going wrong?  I think I may be setting up the paper size for both the document and the printer incorrectly. I've tried numerous other paper sizes and to no avail.

Thanks For Any Help.

Comment: Printers can be cranky about custom paper sizes.  Have you tried *not* setting the paper size so you'll just use the default that was selected by the driver?  Configure the driver as necessary to select that size.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply Hans. I've tried that also but it's still refusing to print as the document is too large.

Comment: Providing code that compiles would be helpful.  `new PaperSize("Custom Size, 212, 67);` ?

Comment: So, what's the paper size you selected on the printer driver with its Printer preferences?

Comment: Sorry Peter. That was a typo. It still doesnt work when it compiles.

Comment: What are the margin settings?  You can query the margin settings in code with PrintPageEventArgs.MarginBounds.

Comment: Hans I've Tried Almost All The Paper Size Options That The PrinterSetting.PaperSize Array Suggests, i.e. PaperSize pS = new PaperSize("Custom", 244, 393);

Comment: Peter...When I Call To String On The MarginBounds I Get The Following: {X=100,Y=100,Width=154,Height=-86}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was not a programming problem but a printer configuration problem. By default the printer was configured to use a different paper size other than the one I was using. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. Your comment helped me with a similar issue. It appears that these Brother label printers plainly ignore the PageSettings properties.. once you have it working try putting some wild values in there. Completely ignored - crazy! Set a large enough print area and ensure that you are drawing within the right rectangle and you'll be fine.